# How to create unit tests for visual components

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, user-interface

I'm the author of [ScadaJS](https://github.com/aktos-io/scada.js) and I need to create unit tests for visual components. Up to now, the components are checked manually by human interaction.

For example, [this bug](https://github.com/aktos-io/scada.js/issues/63#issue-206236493) simply describes what the problem is with a visual component by screenshots. Reporter says "it should look like `this` but looks like `that` and this is not something expected". Developers fix the component, check it manually in the showcase page and close the issue if everything goes well.

As one component's changes may break more than one other component, I think we should automate these tests. How do the people perform such checks in libraries where the visual stuff come into play?

## A guess

We could write a script that will automatically create mouse movements and clicks, then it will create a `.gif` which will be used to create a reference point. If anything changes, difference of two gifs won't be a black `.gif`, so the test suit will throw an exception. If we set a flag to indicate "everything is OK with this component, I only changed the font size", then it will use new `.gif` as a reference point.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) could be something worth to checkout. Image compare could be one option but I don't think it is very usable. Even slightest change in the component would break the test and storing reference images is pretty tedious job.

Comment: This is very close what I needed. Maybe such a testing framework could be created based on Selenium.